# Print a variable in single quote on bash | Weird Variables

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, quoting, variable

On bash script, I need to pass date as ansible extra variable but getting something `single quotes` related issues;

```
...
$DT="03-04-17"
ansible-playbook copy2s3.yml --extra-vars 'cdate={{ "$DT" }}'
```

and manually ansible-playbook working like

```
$ ansible-playbook copy2s3.yml --extra-vars 'cdate={{ "03-04-17" }}'
```

Here I dynamically pass the date on ansible playbook.

Comment: Try `ansible-playbook copy2s3.yml --extra-vars "'cdate={{ 03-04-17 }}'"`

Comment: @cuonglm here i need to pass `$DT` variable on script, manually it's working as you say

Comment: I mean `"'cdate={{ $DT }}'"`

Comment: Complete output like  'cdate={{ "03-04-17" }}'  but date comes from `DT` variable.

Comment: Then it would be `"'cdate={{ \"$DT\" }}'"`

Comment: If I store this on variable and echo then show output fine but if I pass on ansible then getting error: " FAILED! => failed: true, msg: "the field args has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: cdate is undefined"

Answer (score 2):

`ansible-playbook copy2s3.yml --extra-vars 'cdate={{ "$DT" }}'`

The ansible-playbook command (repeated above) is not going to see your single quotes anyway.
What it would see are the following:

- arg#1    `copyy2s3.yml`
- arg#2    `--extra-vars`
- arg#3    `cdate={{ "$DT" }}`

Note that the $DT will be a literal string and not a shell variable as also those spaces, which will be part of the argument. There are many ways you can do this as has already been shown to you by Cuonglm.

- `'cdate={{ "'"$DT"'" }}'`
- `'cdate={{ '\""$DT"\"' }}'`
- `"cdate={{ \"$DT\" }}"`
- `cdate=\{\{\ \""$DT"\"\ \}\}`